# How to get current activity in other app using windows api?

Tags: c#, c++, api

I wanna get current activity of other running application like typing,clicking a button or scroll a listview,by using windows api.
after searching i found that there is ways to send message to desired application to do some kind of work,like clicking a button, this action can be performed by SendMessage() API function,i wonder is there any way to know that what action is doing in active window?
I found that we can use GetMessage() function,but it will work to my application itself and not to the other application.
I'm need a little help to know find my way...
thank u!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a low level of abstraction you can get info about fundamental input actions via *Windows hooks* (see `SetWindowsHookEx`).

The abstraction level you seem to desire is however not directly available via the Windows API. I suspect the support for *Computer Based Training* (that includes `SetWindowsHookEx`) is in the direction of what you want. But only as far as it goes.

In short, for high level meaningful information you're very much dependent on the application itself providing that information, e.g. via some automation interface.

Comment: than u my friend. can i get application message list using it's thread and then process message type to understand action type?

Comment: thank you my friend,I think that's it,but i have to more trying on that.